# Parallax effect with recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have following layout with `RecyclerView` and `AppBarLayout`. I am getting perfect view but not getting parallax effect, recyclerView is just scrolling in bottom area of screen.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/splash"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can anyone please help me why parallax is not working? What is wrong in my xml file?

Comment: Add this attribute to your image view. app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" This may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0

if not than update it

Comment: Thanks, its working like charm, thanks for saving my day.

Comment: @Ravi since some days you can update to 23.0.1, stay updated